# iPhone SDK - Number of days between day and today

Tags: iphone, nsdate

I need help on how to find out how many days it has been (seven day weeks, MSTimezone) since May 6th, 2009

`[NSDate *m62009 = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:231638400];
[m62009 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"MST"];` (to help you - 231638400 seconds from 1/1/2001)

---

Edit:
And then how can I convert the NSTimeInterval into days as an integer or string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654412/calculate-time-difference-in-cocoa), but the solution you're looking for should be something like the following:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

NSDate *date1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2009-05-06"];
NSDate *date2 = [NSDate date]; // Should produce today's date

NSTimeInterval diff = [date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1]
```

You can then format the NSTimeInterval as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest relaying this through another integer saying "Set *integer created for this use here* to (That comparing day's number out of 365 - Today's day number out of 365)"